# Card Hover Effect

Tags: css, hover

I have made a standard card with an image on the top and text content on the bottom. The image has grayscale and hover effects applied that work as expected. The card title has an after element scale effect that also works correctly. The read more link has an after element scale effect that works as I expect. When hovering anywhere on the card the title animation works as I would like it to but the image effects do not apply. I would like all the effects (minus the read more) to apply when the card is hovered. For the life of me I cannot figure out why this doesn't work.

Beginning developer, first time poster. Be gentle.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card__image-container {
  border-radius: 0.8rem 0.8rem 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card> :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card__image {
  display: block;
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
  border-radius: 0.8rem 0.8rem 0 0;
  filter: grayscale(75%);
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  @extend .transition;
}

.card__image:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.card__content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2.5rem;
}

.card__title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card__title::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.25rem;
  left: -2.5rem;
  bottom: -0.25rem;
  width: calc(100% + 1rem);
  background: #999797;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scalex(0.02);
  transform-origin: left;
  @extend .transition;
}

.card:hover .card__title::after {
  transform: scalex(1);
  border-radius: 0 0.8rem 0.8rem 0;
}

.card__content {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.card__link {
  color: #999797;
  position: relative;
}

.card__link::after {
  background-color: #999797;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 38%;
  transform: scalex(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  @extend .transition;
}

.card__link:hover::after {
  transform: scalex(1);
}
```

```html
<li class="card">
  <div class="card__image-container">
    <img class="card__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="Placeholder">
  </div>
  <div class="card__content-container">
    <h3 class="card__title">Something About Something</h3>
    <p class="card__content">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic molestias eius dolor quasi.</p>
    <a class="card__link" href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <
```

Comment: For the image you have 

'.card__image:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}'

And it works. It's not clear what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: If you hover anywhere on the card the animation behind the title works. If you hover anywhere but on the image the image animation does not work. I would like both animations to work regardless of where you hover on the card. For example, if you hover over the paragraph text the title animation works. The image animation should also work if you hover over the paragraph rather than just the image. All of my elements are children of .card so I do not know why one works and the other does not.

Comment: Then you need Javascript.

Comment: Thank you, Azu. I wasn't sure if it could be done with just css. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No, this does not need JavaScript - you just need to do the _same_ thing you did for the hover effect for the title, for the image. But you did them differently for some reason. `.card:hover .card__title::after` - you are formatting the after element of the title differently, when the whole card gets hovered. But the image, you are only formatting differently, when it _itself_ gets hovered: `.card__image:hover` That latter selector should be `.card:hover .card__image` instead.

Comment: I figured that out after taking a break from it for a minute. Thank you for posting the correct solution.